# Node.js .map function causing express server to return the response object early

Tags: node.js, express, return, anonymous-function, array.prototype.map

My goal is to create an abstracted POST function for an express running on Node similar to Django's inbuilt REST methods. As a part of my abstracted POST function I'm checking the database (mongo) for valid foreign keys, duplicates, etc..., which is where we are in the process here. The function below is the one that actually makes the first calls to mongo to check that the incoming foreign keys actually exist in the tables/collections that they should exist in.

In short, the inbuilt response functionality inside the native `.map` function seems to be causing an early `return` from the called/subsidiary functions, and yet still continuing on inside the called/subsidiary functions after the early `return` happens.

Here is the code:

```js
const db = require(`../../models`)

const findInDB_by_id = async params => {

  console.log(`querying db`)

  const records = await Promise.all(Object.keys(params).map(function(table){
    return db[table].find({
      _id: {
        $in: params[table]._ids
      }
    })
  }))
  console.log('done querying the db')

  // do stuff with records
  return records
}

// call await findIndDB_by_id and do other stuff
// eventually return the response object
```

And here are the server logs

> querying db
> POST <route> <status code> 49.810 ms - 9  //<- and this is the appropriate response
> done querying the db
> ... other stuff

When I the function is modified so that the map function doesn't return anything, (a) it doesn't query the database, and (b) doesn't return the express response object early. So by modifying this:

```js
const records = await Promise.all(Object.keys(params).map(function(table){
    return db[table].find({ // going to delete the `return` command here
      _id: {
        $in: params[table]._ids
      }
    })
  }))
```

to this

```
const records = await Promise.all(Object.keys(params).map(function(table){
    db[table].find({ // not returning this out of map
      _id: {
        $in: params[table]._ids
      }
    })
  }))
```

the server logs change to:

> querying db
> done querying the db
> ... other stuff
> POST <route> <status code> 49.810 ms - 9  // <-appropriate reponse

But then I'm not actually building my query, so the query response is empty. I'm experiencing this behavior with the anonymous map function being an arrow function of this format `.map(table => (...))` as well.

Any ideas what's going on, why, or suggestions?

Comment: What database?  Does `db[table].find()` return a promise?

Comment: What is the real problem here?  Please state your problem more clearly?  The first block of code looks correct to me.  Can you show how the calling code works?  Perhaps you're not using that function correctly.

Comment: Where'd you go?  We're trying to help and asking you several questions so we can understand, but you're not here.  Can't help you if you won't participate.  Stackoverflow is not like some online forum where you post and come back 8 hours later.  You're either here to participate or you'll miss the people that attempt to help you and perhaps accumulate downvotes for being non-responsive or for having an unclear question.

Comment: @jfriend00 `db[table].find()` is a mongoose find function calling the variable `table` in the `db` collection. The real problem is that when the `.map` includes an explicitly stated `return` or an *implicitly* stated return, the return seems to be being applied to the calling function instead of the `.map` function, which is just bizzare

Comment: Your statement "the return seems to be being applied to the calling function instead of the .map function," is not clear to me.  Please show an explicit code example, perhaps annotated with `console.log()` statements to show the code flow.

Comment: It's confusing to me too. Here is the relevant logs for the above original code - with the return statement inside the map function
`querying db \n POST /api/admin/formFactor 404 51.908 ms -9 \n db query finished`  
and without the return statement:  
`querying db \n db query finished`

Comment: So, what is confusing about the first set of server logs.  That looks exactly as I would expect - that is how it is supposed to work.  The `await` pauses execution of the containing function until the promise is resolved so `done querying the db` comes after the db requests.  I still don't see the problem.  But, the caller is not paused.  The caller will get a promise back from your `async` function at the moment that function hits its first `await`.

Comment: The problem is the `POST /api/admin/formFactor 404 53.390 ms - 9` line. That's the server returning the response object to the client. Essentially it's returning the original promise instead of the most recent. It's almost like it's pulling from the bottom of the promise stack instead of the top

Comment: I don't know what "come off the bottom of the stack instead of the top" means.  Please use real world observed results and logging sequences to describe what is happening.  As best I can tell, there's nothing wrong here at all.  Your first set of server logs is exactly how it should be working.  See my  previous comment if you missed that.

Comment: The second version of your code just runs the db queries open loop with no control and no ability to collect results or process errors.  This is often referred to as "fire and forget".  The rest of your code continues to execute without regard for anything happening in those db queries.  It's highly unlikely that the second version of code is correct.  While there are a very few situations where "fire and forget" is appropriate, I will always want to at least log errors in such a situation, but since it appears you want results, this cannot be correct.

Comment: I repeat again.  What problem do you need solved here in the first code example (the second code example is just wrong)?  What code runs before or after it should run?  What results are you not getting?  What wrong result are you getting?  Still don't understand what you need help with.

Comment: As it appears you were confused by how `async` functions work, I attempted to take that part of my comments and put it into an answer to try to finish up this question.  Let me know if that is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version of your code is working as expected and the logs are as expected.

All `async` function return a promise.  So `findInDB_by_id()` will always return a promise.   In fact, they return a promise as soon as the first `await` inside the function is encountered as the calling code continues to run.  The calling code itself needs to use `await` or `.then()` to get the resolved value from that promise.

Then, some time later, when you do a `return someValue` in that function, then `someValue` becomes the resolved value of that promise and that promise will resolve, allowing the calling code to be notified via `await` or `.then()` that the final result is now ready.

`await` only suspends execution of the `async` function that it is in.  It does not cause the caller to be blocked at all.  The caller still has to to deal with a promise returned from the `async` function.

---

The second version of your code just runs the db queries open loop with no control and no ability to collect results or process errors. This is often referred to as "fire and forget". The rest of your code continues to execute without regard for anything happening in those db queries. It's highly unlikely that the second version of code is correct. While there are a very few situations where "fire and forget" is appropriate, I will always want to at least log errors in such a situation, but since it appears you want results, this cannot be correct

Comment: @DavePaquette - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like as when it encounter first async function it start executing rest of the code

```
let promiseArr = []
Object.keys(params).map(function(table){
     promiseArr.push(db[table].find({
      _id: {
        $in: params[table]._ids
      }
    }))
  })

let [records] = await Promise.all(promiseArr)
```

and if you still want to use map approach

```
await Promise.all(Object.keys(params).map(async function(table){
    return await db[table].find({ 
      _id: {
        $in: params[table]._ids
      }
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate `promiseArr`.  Returning a promise from a `.map()` callback will create an array of promises directly which you can use `Promise.all()` on just fine.  I do that all the time.

Comment: Now, there's no need for the `await` in `return await`.  That is not useful.  It's still just an array of promises.